# Load view from an external xib file in storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, xib

I want to use a view throughout multiple viewcontrollers in a storyboard. Thus, I thought about designing the view in an external xib so changes are reflected in every viewcontroller. But how can one load a view from a external xib in a storyboard and is it even possible? If thats not the case, what other alternatives are availble to suit the situation abouve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a custom iOS view class and instantiate multiple copies of it (in IB)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251202/how-do-i-create-a-custom-ios-view-class-and-instantiate-multiple-copies-of-it-i)

Comment: See this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3MawJVxTgk

Answer (score 169, accepted):

My full example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34524346/3681880), but I will provide a summary below.

**Layout**

Add a .swift and .xib file each with the same name to your project. The .xib file contains your custom view layout (using auto layout constraints preferably).

Make the swift file the xib file's owner.

[image]
**Code**

Add the following code to the .swift file and hook up the outlets and actions from the .xib file.

```
import UIKit
class ResuableCustomView: UIView {

    let nibName = "ReusableCustomView"
    var contentView: UIView?

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        label.text = "Hi"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
        contentView = view
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }
}
```

**Use it**

Use your custom view anywhere in your storyboard. Just add a `UIView` and set the class name to your custom class name.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it that loadNibNamed calls init(coder:)? I have a crash trying to adapt your approach.

Comment: @Fishman, if you try to load the view programmatically (rather than from the storyboard), it will crash because it doesn't currently have an `init(frame:)`. See [this tutorial](http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6) for more details.

Comment: Another common cause of crashing is not setting the custom view to the *file's owner*. See the red circle in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I had set the class of the root view instead of the file owner and it was causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @Suragch ResuableCustomView not resizing. displaying the same in all devices. Not changing height & width according to super of custom view.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya, my guess would be that you didn't set the autolayout constraints.

Comment: After adding view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] line before self.addSubview(view) it's working perfectly.

Comment: I try your tutorial, But its creating 2 view at the time. like one above one

Comment: @Kathiresan.M, The custom view that I created as an example here is two views (a label and a button). You can modify the layout to be whatever you want your custom view to look like.

Comment: No iam not telling that. I am telling ResuableCustomView is created one above one.

Comment: @Kathiresan.M, Oh, I see. In that case I don't know what the problem is. Sorry. If you figure it out, leave another comment or answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-55qZYc9qI its very simple just follow the video.

Comment: @Suragch self.addSubview(view) makes no sense for me. As I see it - self must become the same view initialised from xib. ResuableCustomView is not the xib view, instead it contains it. Is it a workaround, and it won't work the other way?

Answer (score 105):

For a while [Christopher Swasey's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40343124/4441541) was the best approach I had found. I asked a couple of the senior devs on my team about it and one of them had **the perfect solution**! It satisfies every one of the concerns that Christopher Swasey so eloquently addressed and it doesn't require boilerplate subclass code(my main concern with his approach). There is **one gotcha**, but other than that it is fairly intuitive and easy to implement.

1. Create a custom UIView class in a .swift file to control your xib. i.e. `MyCustomClass.swift`
2. Create a .xib file and style it as you want. i.e. `MyCustomClass.xib`
3. Set the `File's Owner` of the .xib file to be your custom class (`MyCustomClass`)
4. **GOTCHA:** leave the `class` value (under the `identity Inspector`) for your custom view in the .xib file blank. *So your custom view will have no specified class, but it will have a specified File's Owner.*
5. Hook up your outlets as you normally would using the `Assistant Editor`.

   - NOTE: If you look at the `Connections Inspector` you will notice that your Referencing Outlets do not reference your custom class (i.e. `MyCustomClass`), but rather reference `File's Owner`. Since `File's Owner` is specified to be your custom class, the outlets will hook up and work propery.
6. Make sure your custom class has @IBDesignable before the class statement.
7. Make your custom class conform to the `NibLoadable` protocol referenced below.

   - NOTE: If your custom class `.swift` file name is different from your `.xib` file name, then set the `nibName` property to be the name of your `.xib` file.
8. Implement `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and `override init(frame: CGRect)` to call `setupFromNib()` like the example below.
9. Add a UIView to your desired storyboard and set the class to be your custom class name (i.e. `MyCustomClass`).
10. Watch IBDesignable in action as it draws your .xib in the storyboard with all of it's awe and wonder.

Here is the protocol you will want to reference:

```
public protocol NibLoadable {
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

public extension NibLoadable where Self: UIView {

    public static var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self) // defaults to the name of the class implementing this protocol.
    }

    public static var nib: UINib {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
        return UINib(nibName: Self.nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }

    func setupFromNib() {
        guard let view = Self.nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else { fatalError("Error loading \(self) from nib") }
        addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

And here is an example of `MyCustomClass` that implements the protocol (with the .xib file being named `MyCustomClass.xib`):

```
@IBDesignable
class MyCustomClass: UIView, NibLoadable {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupFromNib()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupFromNib()
    }

}
```

NOTE: If you miss the Gotcha and set the `class` value inside your .xib file to be your custom class, then it will not draw in the storyboard and you will get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when you run the app because it gets stuck in an infinite loop of trying to initialize the class from the nib using the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method which then calls `Self.nib.instantiate` and calls the `init` again.

Comment: Here is another great approach to it, but I feel the above one is still better: https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d

Comment: The approach mentioned by you above works perfectly and applies live previewing right in the storyboard. It's absolutely handy and awesome, big up!

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks a lot!
I think it's the best solution for adding custom views in storyboards

Comment: Not to knock this solution—it's an interesting approach, and the more the merrier, as far as I'm concerned—but for the record I do not agree that this is in any way more straightforward than my answer.

Comment: That's fair. Straightforward was the wrong word to use. I'll update the post.

Comment: FYI: this solution, using constraint definition in `setupFromNib()`, seems to fix certain strange auto-layout issues with auto-sizing table view cells containing XIB -created views.

Comment: Great solution. Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: By far the best solution! I love `@IBDesignable` compatibility. Can't believe why Xcode or UIKit doesn't provide something like this as default when adding a UIView file.

Comment: can't seem to make this one work..  Every time I set File Owner inside my .xib file, it ALSO sets custom class.

Comment: Great answer! Actually you don't need to use a protocol, just move `nibName`, `nib` and `setupFromNib()` into your class and make it return your class name with `Bundle(for: type(of: self))`

Comment: @BenPatch have you been able to avoid boilerplate in all the views with this approach? e.g. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464958/get-the-type-name-of-derived-type-in-a-static-method-of-base-class-or-extension

Comment: I still didn't understand how to link these at storyboard IB

Answer (score 32):

Assuming that you've created an xib that you want to use:

1) Create a custom subclass of UIView (you can go to File -> New -> File... -> Cocoa Touch Class. Make sure "Subclass of:" is "UIView").

2) Add a view that's based on the xib as a subview to this view at initialization.

In Obj-C

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        UIView *xibView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourXIBFilename"
                                                              owner:self
                                                            options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        xibView.frame = self.bounds;
        xibView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self addSubview: xibView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In Swift 2

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let xibView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("YourXIBFilename", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    xibView.frame = self.bounds
    xibView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(xibView)
}
```

In Swift 3

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let xibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourXIBFilename", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! UIView
    xibView.frame = self.bounds
    xibView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(xibView)
}
```

3) Wherever you want to use it in your storyboard, add a UIView as you normally would, select the newly added view, go to the Identity Inspector (the third icon on the upper right that looks like a rectangle with lines in it), and enter your subclass's name in as the "Class" under "Custom Class".

Comment: `xibView.frame = self.frame;` should be `xibView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);`, otherwise xibView will have an offset when the view is added to storyboard.

Comment: late to the party but it seems he changed it to xibView.frame = self.bounds, which is a frame without offset

Comment: Results in a crash due to infinite recursion. Loading the nib creates another instance of the subclass.

Comment: The xib view's class should not be the same as this new subclass. If the xib is MyClass, you can make this new class MyClassContainer.

Comment: the solution above will crash to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 30):

I've always found the "add it as a subview" solution unsatisfactory, seeing as it screws with (1) autolayout, (2) `@IBInspectable`, and (3) outlets. Instead, let me introduce you to the magic of `awakeAfter:`, an `NSObject` method.

`awakeAfter` lets you swap out the object actually woken up from a NIB/Storyboard with a different object entirely. *That* object is then put through the hydration process, has `awakeFromNib` called on it, is added as a view, etc.

We can use this in a "cardboard cut-out" subclass of our view, the only purpose of which will be to load the view from the NIB and return it for use in the Storyboard. The embeddable subclass is then specified in the Storyboard view's identity inspector, rather than the original class. It doesn't actually have to be a subclass in order for this to work, but making it a subclass is what allows IB to see any IBInspectable/IBOutlet properties.

This extra boilerplate might seem suboptimal—and in a sense it is, because ideally `UIStoryboard` would handle this seamlessly—but it has the advantage of leaving the original NIB and `UIView` subclass completely unmodified. The role it plays is basically that of an adapter or bridge class, and is perfectly valid, design-wise, as an additional class, even if it is regrettable. On the flip side, if you prefer to be parsimonious with your classes, @BenPatch's solution works by implementing a protocol with some other minor changes. The question of which solution is better boils down to a matter of programmer style: whether one prefers object composition or multiple inheritance.

Note: the class set on the view in the NIB file remains the same. The embeddable subclass is *only* used in the storyboard. The subclass can't be used to instantiate the view in code, so it shouldn't have any additional logic, itself. It should *only* contain the `awakeAfter` hook.

```
class MyCustomEmbeddableView: MyCustomView {
  override func awakeAfter(using aDecoder: NSCoder) -> Any? {
    return (UIView.instantiateViewFromNib("MyCustomView") as MyCustomView?)! as Any
  }
}
```

⚠️ The one significant drawback here is that if you define width, height, or aspect ratio constraints in the storyboard that don't relate to another view then they have to be copied over manually. Constraints that relate two views are installed on the nearest common ancestor, and views are woken from the storyboard from the inside-out, so by the time those constraints are hydrated on the superview the swap has already occurred. Constraints that only involve the view in question are installed directly on that view, and thus get tossed when the swap occurs unless they are copied.

Note that what is happening here is constraints installed on the view *in the storyboard* are copied to the *newly instantiated view*, which may already have constraints of its own, defined in its nib file. Those are unaffected.

```
class MyCustomEmbeddableView: MyCustomView {
  override func awakeAfter(using aDecoder: NSCoder) -> Any? {
    let newView = (UIView.instantiateViewFromNib("MyCustomView") as MyCustomView?)!

    for constraint in constraints {
      if constraint.secondItem != nil {
        newView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: constraint.firstAttribute, relatedBy: constraint.relation, toItem: newView, attribute: constraint.secondAttribute, multiplier: constraint.multiplier, constant: constraint.constant))
      } else {
        newView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: constraint.firstAttribute, relatedBy: constraint.relation, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: constraint.constant))
      }
    }

    return newView as Any
  }
}
```

`instantiateViewFromNib` is a type-safe extension to `UIView`. All it does is loop through the NIB's objects until it finds one that matches the type. Note that the generic type is the *return* value, so the type has to be specified at the call site.

```
extension UIView {
  public class func instantiateViewFromNib<T>(_ nibName: String, inBundle bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main) -> T? {
    if let objects = bundle.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: nil) {
      for object in objects {
        if let object = object as? T {
          return object
        }
      }
    }

    return nil
  }
}
```

Comment: That is mindboggling. If I'm not mistaken though, this only works "on the storyboard" - if you try to create such a class in code at runtime, I don't think it works.  I believe.

Comment: The subclass should work in code just as well as the original class for all intents and purposes. If you want to load the view from a nib in code you would just instantiate it directly using the same technique. All the subclass does is take the code to instantiate the view from a nib and put it in a hook for the storyboard to use.

Comment: Actually I was wrong—it *would* work just as well if you could instantiate it, but you can't, because the view in the NIB will have the superclass as its type so `instantiateViewFromNib` won't return anything. Not a big deal either way IMO, the subclass is just a contrivance to hook into the storyboard, all the code should be on the original class.

Comment: Great! One thing tripped me up because I have little experience with xibs (I only ever worked with storyboards & programmatic approaches), leaving this here in case it helps someone: in the .xib file, you need to select the top level view, and set its class type to `MyCustomView`. In my xib the left inner-sidebar was missing by default; to turn it on, there's a button next to the "View as: iPhone 7" traits control near the bottom/left side.

Comment: It brakes constraints when it replaced by another object. :(

Comment: It's possible you're using constraints in a way that breaks. This method does work transparently with constraints defined in IB.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey One behavior I'm seeing is that constraints added directly to `MyCustomEmbeddableView` in the storyboard (i.e., a fixed height constraint) don't appear to get transferred to the new view. Constraints added from `MyCustomEmbeddableView` to the superview do. In `awakeAfter` of `MyCustomEmbeddableView`, `self.constraints` only has the height constraint and no constraints to the superview, while the `view.constraints` of the new view has all the superview constraints and no height constraint. Have you seen this before?

Comment: @Evan R Looking into it... would be super frustrating if that is the case, and that would explain other mentions of it not working with autolayout. I'm hoping there's a relatively straightforward solution.

Comment: Somewhat improbably, I guess I must never have used this technique with a simple height/width constraint. Other constraints that relate to parent or sibling views are installed on higher views in the hierarchy, so by the time they get hooked up the awakeAfter has swapped out the views. Constraints that are installed on the view itself, however, are instantiated as part of the original view decoding. This might be the death knell for this solution. I might could come up with a workaround, but probably at the cost of the simplicity. Will keep noodling on it.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey Yes, this is the behavior I was seeing. A few potential workarounds: if possible, make the width and height constraints as a relation to the superview in the storyboard (i.e., create an equal height constraint to the superview and modify the multiplier) instead of as fixed constraints, or in `awakeAfter` transfer over any fixed height/width constraints from `MyCustomEmbeddableView` to the new instance of `MyCustomView`. You'd just have to recreate those constraints anew save for the constants, as they go to different view hierarchies. I still think your solution is the best.

Comment: I've updated the answer to note the problem with width/height constraints and to add a copy-and-paste solution. It's not as elegant anymore, but it could be a lot worse.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey I've found what seems to be another issue with this approach—I'm seeing very frequent crashes with using size class-based constraints on the view (i.e., height = x for regular width devices only, constraint not installed for all cases). The exception thrown is very vague and took a while to track down.

Comment: @EvanR Damn. The edge cases are piling up. That one might be intractable, if references are somehow being kept to the height/width constraint objects that are being copied and dumped. Will noodle on this but not hopeful. If only storyboards respected awakeAfter: before it did its thing... although I guess then it wouldn't be `awakeAfter`

Answer (score 9):

Although the top most popular answers works fine, they are conceptually wrong. They all use `File's owner` as connection between class's outlets and UI components. `File's owner` is supposed to be used only for top-level objects not `UIView`s. Check out [Apple developer document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html).
Having UIView as `File's owner` leads to these undesirable consequences.

1. You are forced to use `contentView` where you are supposed to use `self`. It’s not only ugly, but also structurally wrong because the intermediate view keeps data structure from conveying it’s UI structure. It's like going against the concept of declarative UI.
2. You can only have one UIView per Xib. An Xib is supposed to have multiple UIViews.

There's elegant way to do it without using `File's owner`. Please check this [blog post](https://dev.to/ingun37/file-s-owner-is-not-for-uiview-3n9g). It explains how to do it the right way.

Comment: it doesn't not matter at all you didn't explained why its bad. I can't see why. there are no side effects.

Answer (score 7):

I think about `alternative` for using `XIB views` to be using `View Controller` **in separate storyboard**.

Then in main storyboard in place of custom view use `container view` with `Embed Segue` and have `StoryboardReference` to this **custom view controller** which view should be placed inside other view in main storyboard.

Then we can **set up delegation** and communication between this embed ViewController and main view controller through **prepare for segue**. This approach is **different** then displaying UIView, but much simpler and more efficiently (from programming perspective) can be utilised to achieve the same goal, i.e. have reusable custom view that is visible in main storyboard

The additional advantage is that you can implement you logic in CustomViewController class and there set up all delegation and view preparation without creating separate (harder to find in project) controller classes, and without placing boilerplate code in main UIViewController using Component. I think this is good for reusable components ex. Music Player component (widget like) that is embeddable in other views.

Comment: Indeed sadly much more simple solution than using custom view xib :(

Comment: after going in circles with apple's xib lifecycle creation chain on custom UIView this is the way I ended up going.

Comment: In case if you want to add the custom view dynamically, we still have to go with separate view controller (most preferably XIB)

Answer (score 6):

Best solution currently is to just use a custom view controller with its view defined in a xib, and simply delete the "view" property that Xcode creates inside the storyboard when adding the view controller to it (don't forget to set the name of the custom class though).

This will make the runtime automatically look for the xib and load it. You can use this trick for any kind of container views, or content view.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Objective-C according to steps described in [Ben Patch's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295926/3293172).

Use extension for UIView:

```
@implementation UIView (NibLoadable)

- (UIView*)loadFromNib
{
    UIView *xibView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    xibView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:xibView];
    [xibView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [xibView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [xibView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [xibView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor].active = YES;
    return xibView;
}

@end
```

Create files `MyView.h`, `MyView.m` and `MyView.xib`.

First prepare your `MyView.xib` as [Ben Patch's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295926/3293172) says so set class `MyView` for File's owner instead of main view inside this XIB.

`MyView.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE @interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView* someSubview;

@end
```

`MyView.m`:

```
#import "MyView.h"
#import "UIView+NibLoadable.h"

@implementation MyView

#pragma mark - Initializers

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self loadFromNib];
        [self internalInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self loadFromNib];
        [self internalInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self loadFromNib];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self internalInit];
}

- (void)internalInit
{
    // Custom initialization.
}

@end
```

And later just create your view programatically:

```
MyView* view = [[MyView alloc] init];
```

**Warning!** Preview of this view will not be shown in Storyboard if you use WatchKit Extension because of this bug in Xcode >= 9.2: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/95616

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer you've wanted all along. You can just create your `CustomView` class, have the master instance of it in a xib with all the subviews and outlets. Then you can apply that class to any instances in your storyboards or other xibs.

No need to fiddle with File's Owner, or connect outlets to a proxy or modify the xib in a peculiar way, or add an instance of your custom view as a subview of itself.

Just do this:

1. Import BFWControls framework
2. Change your superclass from `UIView` to `NibView` (or from `UITableViewCell` to `NibTableViewCell`)

That's it!

It even works with IBDesignable to refer your custom view (including the subviews from the xib) at design time in the storyboard.

You can read more about it here:
https://medium.com/build-an-app-like-lego/embed-a-xib-in-a-storyboard-953edf274155

And you can get the open source BFWControls framework here:
https://github.com/BareFeetWare/BFWControls

And here's a simple extract of the `NibReplaceable` code that drives it, in case you're curious: https://gist.github.com/barefeettom/f48f6569100415e0ef1fd530ca39f5b4

Tom

Comment: I don't want to install a framework when it should be provided natively.

Comment: @JBarros35: I also wish it was provided natively, but unfortunately it is not. That's why I created the framework. You can instead write your own code based on the small gist source code I posted above, or by picking at the source code of the open source BFWControls framework above. But, that's a lot more work. Good luck .

Answer (score 0):

This solution can be used even if your class does not have the same name as the XIB.
For example, if you have a base view controller class controllerA which has a XIB name controllerA.xib and you subclassed this with controllerB and want to create an instance of controllerB in a storyboard, then you can:

- create the view controller in the storyboard
- set the class of the controller to the controllerB
- delete the view of the controllerB in the storyboard
- override load view in controllerA to:

*

```
- (void) loadView    
{
        //according to the documentation, if a nibName was passed in initWithNibName or
        //this controller was created from a storyboard (and the controller has a view), then nibname will be set
        //else it will be nil
        if (self.nibName)
        {
            //a nib was specified, respect that
            [super loadView];
        }
        else
        {
            //if no nib name, first try a nib which would have the same name as the class
            //if that fails, force to load from the base class nib
            //this is convenient for including a subclass of this controller
            //in a storyboard
            NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
            NSString *pathToNIB = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource: className ofType:@"nib"];
            UINib *nib ;
            if (pathToNIB)
            {
                nib = [UINib nibWithNibName: className bundle: [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
            }
            else
            {
                //force to load from nib so that all subclass will have the correct xib
                //this is convenient for including a subclass
                //in a storyboard
                nib = [UINib nibWithNibName: @"baseControllerXIB" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
            }

            self.view = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

class BYTXIBView: UIView {
var nibView: UIView?

```
// MARK: - init methods
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonSetup()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonSetup()
}

func commonSetup() {
    guard let nibView = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    nibView.frame = bounds
    nibView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(nibView)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let className = type(of: self).className
    let view = bundle.loadNibNamed(className, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView
    return view
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).