# UIView loaded from Xib does not apply AutoLayout correctly

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, xib, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to break up my view controller content into smaller chunks of single views that I load from xib. I'm doing that by placing placeholder `UIView` objects into my Storyboard view controllers and use them to add the actual `UIView` subclass that I have laid out in a xib file as a subview at build time.

The process is pretty straightforward and was [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282365/load-view-from-an-external-xib-file-in-storyboard) [before](https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d).

The problem, however, is that the AutoLayout constraints, defined in the xib file, are not working when I add the view.

To illustrate the problem, I've created a sample project: A `ViewController` has a `colorView` of type `CustomColorView` (subclass of `UIView`) that will be added to a plain `UIView` placeholder. The `CustomColorView`class then has a property of `coloredView` which should fill the out the whole space (defined by AutoLayout constraints to every side in the xib file).

[image: ViewController]

[image]

`NibLoadable` protocol:

```
public protocol NibLoadable {
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

public extension NibLoadable where Self: UIView {

    public static var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }

    public static var nib: UINib {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
        return UINib(nibName: Self.nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }

    func setupFromNib() {
        guard let loadedView = Self.nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else { fatalError("Error loading \(self) from nib") }
        loadedView.frame = bounds

        addSubview(loadedView)
        loadedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        loadedView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        loadedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        loadedView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        loadedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

When I add my custom view to the plain `UIView`, I would assume that it applies all the defined constraints from the nib file but it doesn't. The `print` result should be the same for both view but they are different (`coloredView` still has it's size from the xib file).

Any ideas on what might go wrong? Thanks for your help!

The whole project is up on GitHub: [XibAutoLayoutExample](https://github.com/janheiermann/XibAutoLayoutExample)

Comment: Whole View Controller should be filled with blue view?

Comment: your view heigth is correct please add layer.borderColor and layer.borderWidth and check it

Comment: You cannot get the correct frames on `viewDidLoad` as there it will start loading and layout the views, you can check the real values on `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way? @JanApotheker

Answer (score 1):

Your view height is correct please add `layer.borderColor` and `layer.borderWidth` and check it

```
func setup() {
    print("CustomColorView bounds: \(bounds)")
    print("coloredView subview bounds: \(coloredView.bounds)")
    self.coloredView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    self.coloredView.layer.borderWidth = 1
}
```

Also if you call `setup()` in `viewDidAppear` will show the correct values that is because `viewDidAppear` is executed after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so when your viewController ends its layout correctly your log show the right values

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    colorView.setup()
}
```

**Log**

```
CustomColorView bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 227.0)
coloredView subview bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 227.0)
```

Comment: I agree with you expect that `viewWillAppear` doesn't guarantee that you will have the correct values. You should put that under `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: yes thats right but `viewDidAppear` is executed after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as I think (correct me if I am wrong) so I use `viewDidAppear` not `viewWillAppear` @EridB

Comment: in fact if you put `colorView.setup()` in `viewWillAppear` will get the same wrong values @EridB

Comment: You are right, I read it wrong, I didn't notice it was `viewDidAppear`. On this context it is the right answer! 
P.S The best practice is to check  `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in general as you might have views that you layout manually after the view has appeared!

Comment: you are right, anyway I had updated my answer with a little further clarification @EridB

Comment: Yes, I get the right values in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` too but that does not feel right. I want the view to layout itself correctly without the need for the view controller to update the view's layout.

Comment: the problem is that the `UIView` will adjust the layout once is displayed and not before @JanApotheker

Comment: Is there a way for the `UIView` to know when it is displayed?