# Loading UIView from XIB using Storyboard - view's properties are nil

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, xib

I've created a view:

```
import UIKit

class TestNotWorkingView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
}
```

And connected with the corresponding XIB:
[image: xib]

Then, I've added the view to the UIViewController on the Storyboard:

[image: view on storyboard]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var testNotWorkingView: TestNotWorkingView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(testNotWorkingView)
    print(testNotWorkingView.label1)
}
```

}

When I run the app, only the parent view appears. No labels are visible:

**Parent view:**

> Optional(TestProject.TestNotWorkingView: 0x7fb165e04610; frame = (0
>   0; 414 818); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = CALayer: 0x600001f254e0)

**Querying one of the labels**

> nil

I've already set the `TestNotWorkingView` as the view's class and file owner.

I assume since the views are not present on the storyboard, they're not being created and linked at runtime.

**How can I use views created in XIBs inside a ViewController created in Storyboard? Is it possible at all?**

[Test Project that fully reproduces the issue](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/files/3177615/TestProject.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Using view designed in xib can be a bit tricky, you need to add this code to your TestNotWorkingView class:

```
override func awakeAfter(using aDecoder: NSCoder) -> Any? {
    guard subviews.isEmpty else {
        return self
    }
    return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TestNotWorkingView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first
}
```

EDIT: also, you should leave File's Owner Empty, and connect outlets only to TestNotWorkingView

Comment: Didn't solve the issue - https://pastebin.com/LEf4Wg9Y

Comment: @RichardTopchiy My bad, I forgot to mention that you need to leave File's Owner empty, and connect any outlets to view instead of file's owner.

Comment: same result with your second suggestion

Comment: This may or may not work... The answer from "Ben Patch" at this question (suggested duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282365/load-view-from-an-external-xib-file-in-storyboard is much, much more flexible and reliable.

Comment: That one actually worked