# Is there a more optimised/ efficient way to create custom UIView directly from XIB, in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Assume I have a custom `UIView` class `ColorWheelView.swift` and XIB `ColorWheelView.xib`.

To create an custom `UIView` from XIB via code, here's the common practice

---

### Via Code

```
extension UIView {
    static func instanceFromNib() -> Self {
        return getUINib().instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! Self
    }
    
    static func getUINib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
    }
}

// Create ColorWheelView from XIB.
let colorWheelView = ColorWheelView.instanceFromNib()
```

---

### Via Storyboard (Doesn't look like a right way)

But, how about Storyboard? What if I use `ColorWheelView` as a subview in Storyboard? How can I inform Storyboard that `ColorWheelView` should be constructed **directly** from `ColorWheelView.xib`?

[image]

A common way I have seen so far is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34524346/72437 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34524583/72437

```
import UIKit

class ColorWheelView: UIView {

    let nibName = "ColorWheelView"
    var contentView: UIView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
        contentView = view
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }
}
```

But, such code just doesn't look right to me. It merely

1. Storyboard creates a "parent" `ColorWheelView` without using XIB.
2. Then, "parent" `ColorWheelView` creates another "child" `ColorWheelView` from XIB, and used it as subview of itself.
3. Doesn't seem like an optimised way, as now we are having 2 instances of `ColorWheelView`.

Is there a better way, to tell Storyboard that I want to create a custom subview from an XIB?

Comment: It's just one more parent view. It won't make much difference in most cases. Are you actually having performance problems with this and found that having one fewer view improves the situation? The alternative to this is to get all the subviews from `nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first`, remove them from their superview, and then add them as subviews of `self`. The code is less convenient to write.

Comment: It is not performance issue. It is just doesn't feel right. Why do we ever need to create 2 instances of same custom views?

Comment: you are not creating two identical view hierarchies, just one extra superview. As I said in my comment, you don’t need to create the extra superview, but it’s more convenient to just do that. It’s a lot of trouble to re-add the sub views from the XIB to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ColorWheelView: UIView {

let nibName = "ColorWheelView"
var contentView: UIView?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    view.frame = self.bounds
    self.addSubview(view)
    contentView = view
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
}
}
```

By putting designable keyword before class name will make this view to be used in storyboard way you want(by putting custom view class name in identity inspector.