# Instantiating custom xib programmatically ends with infinite loop

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I request apologies in advance in the case this question is very elemental or the answer is obvious.

I have a custom xib, that works very well when used with the storyboard interface builder. The custom xib is implemented like the classical samples you can find across the internet:

- I have a CustomView.swift class
- a CustomView.xib file.

The FileOwner of the CustomView.xib file is set to the CustomView.class. Then this xib file has a couple of outlets for the views used in the xib. Something like the following:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomView: UIView {


 @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //When loaded from storyboard.
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        //When loaded from code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {

  
        if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(self.nibName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView {
            view.frame = self.bounds
            self.addSubview(view)
            view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
   
        }

    }

func renderViews()
//A lot of stuff is done here.
}



}
```

As said, this works very well when using the Storyboard designer to insert the custom xib in the layout of an UIController. But I need to use the same xib on another place, and I need to instantiate and insert it programmatically in a container view multiple times.

I tried different approaches to instantiate the xib and add it as a subview of another view, for example:

```
class AnotherView: UIView
(...)
func instantiateXib(){

 let view = CustomView()
  self.addSubView(view)
}
}
```

or

```
  class AnotherView: UIView
    (...)
    func instantiateXib(){
    
      let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)
      let view = nib.first as! CustomView
      self.addSubView(view)
    }
    }
```

or many other ways that I found across the internet, but all of them end with an infinite loop, because the  method init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) of the xib, calls the commonInit method that instantiates again an instance of the xib, and so on.

I suspect the solution is obvious, but I'm struggling to find it.

May you point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you leave the [custom class of your view blank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295926/3418066)?

Comment: "the onInit method of the xib"  What is the onInit method?

Comment: Sorry I mean the init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) method

Comment: @Paulw11; yes, the custom class of the view is blank. Only the fileOwner has a custom class. My code is very similar to the sample you provided. I will try your link, but I suspect the same will happen.

Comment: @Paulw11: Somehow the sample provided in your link, works. Although the code is so similar to mine that I can not explain the reason because your sample works, and mine not. But thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction