# Why I get to error when I change default .xib?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have Main.xib and I added a new Interface SeconView.xib. I want to my secondview.xib to be default.

I changed default xib from Main Interface but I get to error like

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x880ab00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

. Where I did wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118135/how-do-i-solve-a-nsunknownkeyexception-setvalueforundefinedkey-not

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)

Answer (score 1):

check your connection panel whether connection is properly set or not

Answer (score 1):

To change default nib from Main to Second , you need to perform these steps:

- In AppDelegate's method

> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
> ```

Change the argument of initWithNibName from @"Main" to @"Second"

> self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];

- Select `Second.xib`, and
  change its FileOwner to ViewController (or the controller you want to associate this   nib with)
- RighClick on View and drag New Referencing Outlet towards File Owner.

Comment: RightClick on View in Second.xib and please check again whether it is connected to FileOwner's view or not

Comment: It is not connect to FileOwner.Can not connect by right click

Comment: Press LeftClick on mouse and drag New Referencing Outlet to File's Owner

Comment: Thank you but can not drag.It is not available for drag

Comment: Refer to this link. It has an image that is showing what to drag and where to drag.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/csI3r.png

Comment: Yes I see but it can not drag by mouse any way.