# How to find all the NS[whatever]UsageDescription keys my dependencies will require?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, info.plist

I have an Xcode project which depends on a bunch of third-party frameworks. I'd like to start preparing for an app submission and I'm wondering whether Xcode forewarns me of all the `NS[whatever]UsageDescription` keys I'll need to provide.

When I look at the the ***"Info"*** tab in Xcode I only see one of these `Privacy - [whatever] Usage Description` keys. I'm suspicious because I expected to find more.

I'd like to be 100% sure that the frameworks I depend on do not use additional native API's that I'm not aware of *before* I submit my app.

Is there a way for Xcode to search for dependencies? Or is there way to get this programmatically?

Comment: Just to add, I just found a very similar question asked in the Apple developer forums: How to pre-check for privacy violations before sending to App Store / TestFlight? (https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/308163#308163). Seems I'm not the only one troubled by this. No answers there either though.

Comment: And another one in the Apple developer forums: What triggers requests for "usage descriptions"? (https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/196093#196093)

Comment: And another: App review ask me to give location reason while I don't use it (https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/343459#343459). Looks like people are getting somehow past this problem and then neglecting to go back and comment on how they did it. I think the Apple developer community could learn a few things from the one in StackOverflow.

Comment: Over a month and half later, nobody seems to have an answer to this. Not here and not in the Apple developer forums. I think there's simply no programmatic way to do this. Apple is seriously dragging their feet with this issue. There are no tools to tell beforehand what descriptors you may need, so you have no option but just submit your app and pray that Apple doesn't reject it because of some dependency requiring stuff you're unaware of. I think they just do this manually and they may or may not complain about your app. Who knows.