# Swift app crashes on iPhone but not simulator

Tags: ios

Hey guys I am using crashlytics for my app and have the following crash on iPhones, but in simulator it is working just fine, do you have any idea. The think is that user is opening a segue. I don't know is it coming from the segue. or what. Please help

```
Fatal Exception: NSUnknownKeyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1b7ed5c30 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b7bf00c8 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b7dd4bd0 -[NSObject(NSKindOfAdditions) isNSSet__]
3  Foundation                     0x1b827bce4 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter
4  Foundation                     0x1b81bc0f0 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1bb92d06c -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:]
6  UIKitCore                      0x1bbc0264c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect]
7  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b7bebcf8 -[NSObject performSelector:]
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1b7da958c -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x1bbbff640 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
10 UIKitCore                      0x1bb933f08 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:]
11 UIKitCore                      0x1bb9349cc -[UIViewController loadView]
12 UIKitCore                      0x1bb934c9c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired]
13 UIKitCore                      0x1bb935384 -[UIViewController view]
14 UIKitCore                      0x1bb85b230 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:]
15 UIKitCore                      0x1bb84e9f8 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:]
16 UIKitCore                      0x1bb945320 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:]
17 UIKitCore                      0x1bb947fb4 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke
18 UIKitCore                      0x1bb948518 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:]
19 UIKitCore                      0x1bb947f00 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]
20 UIKitCore                      0x1bb948194 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]
21 UIKitCore                      0x1bb94c4fc -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:]
22 UIKitCore                      0x1bc0bfaa0 __66-[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke
23 UIKitCore                      0x1bc0c4ed8 -[UIStoryboardSegue perform]
24 UIKitCore                      0x1bc0c5854 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:]
25 UIKitCore                      0x1bc0c56f8 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:]
26 UIKitCore                      0x1bb937ba4 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]
27 LBBW                           0x1003bdf1c specialized SlideOutNavigation.openChanageLoginView(_:)
28 LBBW                           0x1003b9098 @objc SlideOutNavigation.openImprint(_:) (<compiler-generated>)
29 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b7bebd5c -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:]
30 UIKitCore                      0x1bbf6cb44 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
31 UIKitCore                      0x1bb98910c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
32 UIKitCore                      0x1bb989480 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
33 UIKitCore                      0x1bb988490 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
34 UIKitCore                      0x1bbfa768c -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
35 UIKitCore                      0x1bbfa897c -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
36 UIKitCore                      0x1bbf84804 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
37 UIKitCore                      0x1bbffe224 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
38 UIKitCore                      0x1bc0007dc __handleEventQueueInternal
39 UIKitCore                      0x1bbff9960 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain
40 CoreFoundation                 0x1b7e51260 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
41 CoreFoundation                 0x1b7e511b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
42 CoreFoundation                 0x1b7e50920 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
43 CoreFoundation                 0x1b7e4b7ec __CFRunLoopRun
44 CoreFoundation                 0x1b7e4b098 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
45 GraphicsServices               0x1c1fb5534 GSEventRunModal
46 UIKitCore                      0x1bbf6b7ac UIApplicationMain
47 LBBW                           0x10033441c main + 37 (AppDelegate.swift:37)
48 libdyld.dylib
```

Comment: `48 libdyld.dylib             ou what is the standard font size and color for message inside the alerts in swift. I want to now the size and the color and also if there is a family too. Thanks!`
Is that really part of the stacktrace?

Comment: for some reason, one of my old questions was in this one, I am sorry, I am under stress about this crash, eddites

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118135/how-do-i-solve-a-nsunknownkeyexception-setvalueforundefinedkey-not

Comment: do you know the reason here

Comment: and did you check the bad links/ connections, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/xcode-how-to-fix-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-valu (possibly something related to `specialized SlideOutNavigation.openChanageLoginView(_:)`).