# How do I add my new View to the storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I started with the template Master/Detail project. I then added another `ViewController`, with a xib. I'd like this view to be the one that is displayed when the app launches. The problem is I can't figure out how to add it to the Storyboard.

I can add a new empty view to the Storyboard, but I can't link it up with the `ViewController` files I just created. Do I need to start again by adding a new view to the Storyboard, laying out my view there?

Comment: Try copy-paste. Select view in ViewController.xib -> Press Command+c -> Go to storyboard -> Press Command+v

Comment: I also believe copy +paste should do it, also similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251202/how-do-i-create-a-custom-ios-view-class-and-instantiate-multiple-copies-of-it-i/9251254#9251254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be easiest, if you just make that new view in the storyboard. If you have a complicated view that you set up in your xib, you can copy and paste into a new controller in the storyboard (delete the empty view from the controller first). After, you've copied your view into the new controller, you can change its class to the subclass you made.

Comment: Ok, that's what I've done, but now I can't link up my `IBOutlet`s to the storyboard, the draggy lines from my `ViewController.h` refuse to connect.

Comment: @TomMedley, did you change the class of the view controller to your subclass?