# Loading Custom View Using Nib

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Getting bad excess loading nib file

File owner: NDAccountView
Class Name:  NDAccountView

[image]

Any Help will really be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is `nib` a valid object?  If you get rid of the `as! UIView`, what kind of object is loaded into `view`?

Comment: @PhillipMills it is UIView object. I have fixed the issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Mistake as I was setting root view class as my file's owner class name so I have changed Root view class to UIView and everything working fine.

I have followed this link: [Custom View Class Proper way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35922837/1242673)