# Xcode not giving debug information on crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app is crashing, but there is no additional information as to why. When I go to a certain view controller, it requires loading a custom `UIView` from a nib. The line to load the nib is where I am getting the crash.

I get an error message of

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16b547db8)

but there is no output to the console or further information.

Scheme is set to debug. I've tried intentionally making an error in the spelling of the nib name, and that gives me all of the necessary debug information in the console.

The line causing the crash is:

```
let v = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HelpPageSection", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! HelpPageSection
```

Comment: check  have  you set class name of .XIB file HelpPageSection

Comment: I think that you have an infinite loop here leading to a memory issue. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/35922837/2290372

Comment: I have done this.

Comment: Have you set both File's Owner AND Custom Class in Interface Builder for the nib file? You must only set File's Owner, otherwise you'll get an endless loop on instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

To load an xib:-

```
let v = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HelpPageSection", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! HelpPageSection
```

It helps.

Answer (score 0):

I added some comments to print when the initializer was being called, and it was indeed an infinite loop. However, there were still issues. I tried a slightly different way of loading the nib and it works. I connected the base view of the xib file as an IBOutlet, then used this code:

```
@IBOutlet var main: UIView!
func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HelpPageSection", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.main)
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commonInit()
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.commonInit()
}
```

Comment: It does, however, seem strange to me that the nib loading line appears to be an unused result, and that the adding of the subview is not necessarily related to it. I must be misunderstanding how the nib loading function works...