# Load Nib for UIView used in ViewController in StoryBoard

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, nib, iso

I have a UIView that I want to use in several View Controllers so I created the view (.h/.m) and a nib file for it. In Storyboard view is added as subview to view controller but is not loading the layout as defined in nib.

Is it possible to load the nib for a UIView used within a view controller in a Storyboard?

Comment: Here is a [Swift example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34524346/3681880)

Answer (score 18):

If you ask about **seeing your .xib content in Interface Builder** when editing Storyboard, it's **not possible**. But if you need to load it in runtime, **it's possible**.

- **.h/.m** should contain **UIView** subclass
- in **.xib** file you need to set **File's owner** (*Identity Inspector -> Custom Class*) with your custom UIView subclass
- in **.h** file add `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView* view;` and connect your View container from Interface Builder to this field (*Ctrl + Click* on View and drag connection to above `view` property in .h
- connect other subviews to **.h**
- in **.m** file you need to place

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSString* nibName = @"Place here your Nib name without extension";
    if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil]) {
        [self.view setFrame:[self bounds]];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
}
```

That's all. Move **View to Storyboard scene**, change **Custom Class** to your *FooView*, import .h in View Controller code and use **IBOutlets** as you want.

Have happy coding

**EDIT**

I want to notice that according `awakeFromNib` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib) we should avoid such code in `awakeFromNib`.

> It is recommended that you maintain a one-to-one correspondence between your File’s Owner objects and their associated nib files. Loading two nib files with the same File’s Owner object causes that object’s awakeFromNib method being called twice, which could cause some data structures to be reinitialized in undesired ways. It is also recommended that you avoid loading other nib files from your awakeFromNib method implementation.

Comment: So if I have FooView.h/.m & FooView.xib and have added FooView to a ViewController in Storyboard and created IBOutlet of it in ViewController. What I am not clear on is the "view" property of FooView. Is this needed, or can the FooView that is defined in ViewController of Storyboard be instantiated or awaken in another way?

Comment: @tiltem usually you create **View Controller** and .xib in couple. So all binding of top view container (in .xib) and **view** property in VC is made automatically in such case. Here you want to bind UIView to .xib. So you need to do this routine work manually. But it allows you to use Auto Layout in .xib and Storyboard too. It's minimal price for that. Is it clear now?

Comment: you can find helpful this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)

Comment: This is rarely described but extremely valuable piece of explanation. I love it. The same method is mentioned here: http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2013/07/ios-creating-reusable-uiviews-with-storyboard/

Comment: Hmm.. may be I did not get what you are saying here.  Are you suggesting to add the above code (loadNibNamed) in the class that you are loading?  Would not this go in infinite loop?

Comment: @ShirishKumar yeap, in fact it's not calling twice but see my update

Answer (score 10):

Name your view `ViewInNib`, then we have:

1. ViewInNib.h
2. ViewInNib.m
3. ViewInNib.xib

In your storyboard, put a `placeholder` UIView component in the view controller, remember to set it's class `ViewInNib`, then in `ViewInNib.m`:

```
static BOOL isReplaced = NO;
- (id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (!isReplaced) 
    {
        isReplaced = YES;
        ViewInNib *replaced = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewInNib" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
        replaced.frame = self.frame;
        replaced.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        return replaced;
    }
    isReplaced = NO;
    return self;
}
```

In this method, we replace real view loaded from nib from view in storyboard. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is very intriguing, but I can't get it to work. Should it still necessary to set the File's Owner as in Anton Gaeko's answer? Does this have any disadvantages with respect to that answer's approach?

Comment: Now, you may try "pod search XXNibBridge"

Comment: Why are we setting isReplaced = YES in the if block, if we set isReplaced = NO right after? Doesn't that override the setting in the if block? Is this an error?

Comment: BEcause there's a return in the if statement so setting it to 'no' is never reached.  On a side note, that statement is unneeded anyway because the only way it can reach that code is if it's already set to no.

Answer (score 4):

use XXNibBridge:

https://github.com/sunnyxx/XXNibBridge

Super simple to use and works with Swift as well.
Full credit goes to @sunnyxx

Comment: I used it successfully in Swift, thank you so much!!