# How to embed a custom view xib in a storyboard scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I'm relatively new in the XCode/iOS world; I've done some decent sized storyboard based apps, but I didn't ever cut me teeth on the whole nib/xib thing. I want to use the same tools for scenes to design/layout a reusable view/control. So I created my first ever xib for my view subclass and painted it up:

[image]

I have my outlets connected and constraints setup, just like I'm used to doing in the storyboard. I set the class of my `File Owner` to that of my custom `UIView` subclass. So I assume I can instantiate this view subclass with some API, and it will configured/connected as shown.

Now back in my storyboard, I want to embed/reuse this. I'm doing so in a table view prototype cell:

[image]

I've got a view. I've set the class of it to my subclass. I've created an outlet for it so I can manipulate it.

The $64 question is where/how do I indicate that it's not enough to just put an empty/unconfigured instance of my view subclass there, but to use the .xib I created to configure/instantiate it? It would be really cool, if in XCode6, I could just enter the XIB file to use for a given UIView, but I don't see a field for doing that, so I assume I have to do something in code somewhere.

*(I do see other questions like this on SO, but haven't found any asking for just this part of the puzzle, or up to date with XCode6/2015)*

### Update

I am able to get this to kind of work by implementing my table cell's `awakeFromNib` as follows:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // gather all of the constraints pointing to the uncofigured instance
    NSArray* progressConstraints = [self.contentView.constraints filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id each, NSDictionary *_) {
        return (((NSLayoutConstraint*)each).firstItem == self.progressControl) || (((NSLayoutConstraint*)each).secondItem == self.progressControl);
    }]];
    // fetch the fleshed out variant
    ProgramProgressControl *fromXIB = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProgramProgressControl" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    // ape the current placeholder's frame
    fromXIB.frame = self.progressControl.frame;
    // now swap them
    [UIView transitionFromView: self.progressControl toView: fromXIB duration: 0 options: 0 completion: nil];
    // recreate all of the constraints, but for the new guy
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *each in progressConstraints) {
        id firstItem = each.firstItem == self.progressControl ? fromXIB : each.firstItem;
        id secondItem = each.secondItem == self.progressControl ? fromXIB : each.secondItem;
        NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: firstItem attribute: each.firstAttribute relatedBy: each.relation toItem: secondItem attribute: each.secondAttribute multiplier: each.multiplier constant: each.constant];
        [self.contentView addConstraint: constraint];
    }
    // update our outlet
    self.progressControl = fromXIB;
}
```

Is this as easy as it gets then? Or am I working too hard for this?

Comment: 1) You should not specify Files's Owner, because you don't have File's owner if xib is just custom view. When you load nib owner parameter should be nil.
2) You should specify Custom Class for your view instead. And connect outlets to this view

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to override initWithCoder in your custom class you assigned the view to.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewYouCreated" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return self; }
```

Once that's done the StoryBoard will know to load the xib inside that UIView.

Here's a more detailed explanation:

This is how your `UIViewController` looks like on your story board:
[image]

The blue space is basically a UIView that will "hold" your xib.

This is your xib:

[image]

There's an Action connected to a button on it that will print some text.

and this is the final result:

[image]

The difference between the first clickMe and the second is that the first was added to the `UIViewController` using the `StoryBoard`. The second was added using code.

Comment: I don't know if it would work, but couldn't you add the view in `layoutSubviews` instead of `initWithCoder:` and make the class `IB_DESIGNABLE`? I guess it would depend on if `IB_DESIGNABLE` classes are capable of loading from the bundle

Comment: I don't know if I misapplied your answer, but it didn't work as expected. In one case, I placed it in the `ProgramProgressControl` class that the .xib has registered as a file owner. In that case, it threw an exception at the `super` send. In the other, I placed it in my table cell subclass, where this is to be placed. The views kind of showed up, but were not even inside of the shell, and I didn't appear to be hooked up to the outlets.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code works but I've found a full example for you that demonstrates how `initWithCoder and` a `xib` file works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251202/how-do-i-create-a-custom-ios-view-class-and-instantiate-multiple-copies-of-it-i/9251254#9251254

Comment: @TravisGriggs I've edited my answer with more examples and an example project you can play with.

Comment: So basicaly, you have to use a 2 view solution. Is that correct? The storyboard has a view that you have an outlet to, and this view has any of the attributes you apply in the storyboard (layout, color, etc). And you then load the XIB instantiated view in as the sole subview of that view. What I was trying to do was swap/merge the "placeholder" view in the storyboard with the one pulled from the XIB. I'm thinking it's not possible, and this double view is the best way to go. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You can't merge two views using the interface builder. Same with swapping. Although our placeholder Custom Class is `DoSomething` it will have the xib as a subview with a file owner of that same class and that's the "trick". You can, however, replace a `UIView` with a xib using just code but that defeats the Purpose of this question.

Comment: Or, instead of overriding initWithCoder, you can override awakeAfterUsingCoder: and do an actual view swap.  Same amount of work, better result.

Answer (score 19):

You need to implement `awakeAfterUsingCoder:` in your custom `UIView` subclass.  This method allows you to exchange the decoded object (from the storyboard) with a different object (from your reusable xib), like so:

```
- (id) awakeAfterUsingCoder: (NSCoder *) aDecoder
{
    // without this check you'll end up with a recursive loop - we need to know that we were loaded from our view xib vs the storyboard.
    // set the view tag in the MyView xib to be -999 and anything else in the storyboard.
    if ( self.tag == -999 )
    {
        return self;
    }

    // make sure your custom view is the first object in the nib
    MyView* v = [[[UINib nibWithNibName: @"MyView" bundle: nil] instantiateWithOwner: nil options: nil] firstObject];

    // copy properties forward from the storyboard-decoded object (self)
    v.frame = self.frame;
    v.autoresizingMask = self.autoresizingMask;
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints;
    v.tag = self.tag;

    // copy any other attribtues you want to set in the storyboard

    // possibly copy any child constraints for width/height

    return v;
}
```

There's a pretty good writeup [here](http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/03/26/reusable/) discussing this technique and a few alternatives.

Furthermore, if you add `IB_DESIGNABLE` to your @interface declaration, and provide an `initWithFrame:` method you can get design-time preview to work in IB (Xcode 6 required!):

```
IB_DESIGNABLE @interface MyView : UIView
@end

@implementation MyView

- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame
{
    self = [[[UINib nibWithNibName: @"MyView"
                            bundle: [NSBundle bundleForClass: [MyView class]]]

             instantiateWithOwner: nil
             options: nil] firstObject];

    self.frame = frame;

    return self;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely preferable to the "use a second wrapping view and add your real view as a subview in initWithCoder" slapdashery. Any heavy context porting can be done in a category/extension method. One suggestion to remove a bit of the configuration: presumably you have subviews in the xib, otherwise it would be pointless, so one might rely on subviews being empty or not instead of the tag property.

Comment: Not possible in swift unfortunately.

Answer (score 16):

A pretty cool and reusable way of doing this Interface Builder and Swift 4:

1. Create a new class like so:

   ```
   import Foundation
   import UIKit

   @IBDesignable class XibView: UIView {

       @IBInspectable var xibName: String?

       override func awakeFromNib() { 
           guard let name = self.xibName, 
                 let xib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(name, owner: self), 
                 let view = xib.first as? UIView else { return }    
           self.addSubview(view)
       }

   }
   ```
2. In your storyboard, add a UIView that will act as the container for the Xib. Give it a class name of `XibView`:

   [image]
3. In the property inspector of this new `XibView`, set the name of your .xib (without the file extension) in the IBInspectable field:

   [image]
4. Add a new Xib view to your project, and in the property inspector, set the Xib's "File's Owner" to `XibView` (ensure you've only set the "File's Owner" to your custom class, DO NOT subclass the content view, or it will crash), and again, set the IBInspectable field:

   [image]

**One thing to note:** This assumes that you're matching the .xib frame to its container. If you do not, or need it to be resizable, you'll need to add in some programmatic constraints or modify the subview's frame to fit. I use [snapkit](/questions/tagged/snapkit) to make things easy:

```
xibView.snp_makeConstraints(closure: { (make) -> Void in
    make.edges.equalTo(self)
})
```

**Bonus points**

Allegedly you can use `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` to make these reusable views visible in Interface Builder, but I haven't had much luck. [This blog](https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d) suggests adding a `contentView` property, and calling the following:

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    xibSetup()
    contentView?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
}
```

Comment: Pretty interesting solution, although I'm getting a warning: "IB Designables: Ignoring user defined runtime attribute for key path "xibName" on instance of "UIView". Hit an exception when attempting to set its value: [<UIView 0x7f8ac2f18f30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key xibName."

Comment: Hrm looks like you maybe have a typo in the name somewhere? My first guess is capital X XibView.

Comment: I don't think so because your solution works great, my XIB is definitely being loaded. If the view didn't have its custom class set properly it wouldn't work at all. It's just the warning that's annoying.

Comment: Oh weird. If you figure it out lemme know.

Comment: ```if let views = xib as? [UIView] where views.count > 0``` in swift syntax changed to ```if let views = xib as? [UIView], views.count > 0```

Comment: also you can change ```self.addSubview(xib[0] as! UIView)``` to ```self.addSubview(views[0] as! UIView)```

Comment: A better format for `awakeFromNib` would be using a guard statement instead of 3 if statements to avoid nesting

example

    `override func awakeFromNib() {
            guard let name = self.xibName,
                let xib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(name, owner: self),
                let views = xib as? [UIView], views.count > 0 else { return }
            self.addSubview(views[0] as! UIView)
        }`

Comment: Apologies for poor formatting, not sure how the formatting on comments work

Comment: Lol they don't. Great addition though! I love `guard`.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to drag and drop `UIView` in your IB and outlet it and set

```
yourUIViewClass  *yourView =   [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourUIViewClass" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
[self.view addSubview:yourView]
```

[image]

## Step

1. Add New File => User Interface => UIView
2. Set Custom Class - yourUIViewClass
3. Set Restoration ID - yourUIViewClass
4. `yourUIViewClass  *yourView =   [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourUIViewClass" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
   [self.view addSubview:yourView]`

Now you can customize view as you want.

Comment: Do I have to set the value of the outlet before a `viewDidLoad`? Or after? Or does it no matter?

Comment: after `viewDidLoad`: because if view is not loaded yet you can't add another subview on it.

Comment: What you're showing here is how to **add** a view fetched from an XIB as a **subview** to a view I created in a storyboard and have an `outlet` to. Which is cool. But what I wanted is to **replace** the view in the storyboard with the XIB one. IOW, I want to use the view in the storyboard like a placeholder. That said, I would like the properties applied to the view in the storyboard (things like background color, layout, etc) to still apply.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using this code snippet for years. If you plan on having custom class views in your XIB just drop this in the .m file of your custom class.

As a side effect it results in awakeFromNib being called so you can leave all your init/setup code in there.

```
- (id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    if ([[self subviews] count] == 0) {
        UIView *view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil][0];
        view.frame = self.frame;
        view.autoresizingMask = self.autoresizingMask;
        view.alpha = self.alpha;
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints;
        return view;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Create xib file 
  `File > New > New File > iOS > User Interface > View`
- Create custom UIView class
  `File > New > New File > iOS > Source > CocoaTouch`
- Assign the xib file's identity to the custom view class
- In viewDidLoad of the view controller initialize the xib and its associated file using `loadNibNamed:` on `NSBundle.mainBundle` and the first view returned can be added as a subview of self.view.
- The custom view loaded from the nib can be saved to a property for setting the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Just set the frame to `self.view`'s frame unless you need to make it smaller than `self.view`.

  ```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

      weak var customView: MyView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          self.customView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! MyView
          self.view.addSubview(customView)
          addButtonHandlerForCustomView()
      }

      private func addButtonHandlerForCustomView() {
          customView.buttonHandler = {
              [weak self] (sender:UIButton) in
              guard let welf = self else {
                  return
              }
              welf.buttonTapped(sender)
          }
      }

      override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
          self.customView.frame = self.view.frame
      }

      private func buttonTapped(button:UIButton) {

      }
  }
  ```
- Also, if you want to talk back from the xib to your `UIViewController` instance then create a weak property on the custom view's class.

  ```
  class MyView: UIView {

      var buttonHandler:((sender:UIButton)->())!

      @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
          buttonHandler(sender:sender)
      }
  }
  ```

Here's the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/philosopherdog/Add_Xib_To_Storyboard.git)

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more swifty version of @brandonscript 's idea with early return:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

    guard let xibName = xibName,
          let xib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibName, owner: self, options: nil),
          let views = xib as? [UIView] else {
        return
    }

    if views.count > 0 {
        self.addSubview(views[0])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't recommend the path you're going down it can be done by placing an "embedded view controller view" where you want the view to appear.

Embed a view controller that contains a single view -- the view you want to be reused.

Comment: This works until you want to put them in things like table cells :)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while on this one, and I've seen a number of answers go by. I recently revisited it because I had just been using UIViewController embedding. Which works, until you want to put something in "an element repeated at runtime" (e.g. a UICollectionViewCell or a UITableViewCell). The link provided by @TomSwift led me to follow the pattern of

A) Rather than make the parent view class be the custom class type, make the FileOwner be the target class (in my example, CycleControlsBar)

B) Any outlet/action linking of the nested widgets goes to that

C) Implement this simple method on CycleControlsBar:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    if let container = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CycleControlsBar", owner: self, options: nil) as? [UIView])?.first {
        self.addSubview(container)
        container.constrainToSuperview() // left as an excise for the student
    }
}
```

Works like a charm and so much simpler than the other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer you've wanted all along. You can just create your `CustomView` class, have the master instance of it in a xib with all the subviews and outlets. Then you can apply that class to any instances in your storyboards or other xibs.

No need to fiddle with File's Owner, or connect outlets to a proxy or modify the xib in a peculiar way, or add an instance of your custom view as a subview of itself.

Just do this:

1. Import BFWControls framework
2. Change your superclass from `UIView` to `NibView` (or from `UITableViewCell` to `NibTableViewCell`)

That's it!

It even works with IBDesignable to render your custom view (including the subviews from the xib) at design time in the storyboard.

You can read more about it here:
https://medium.com/build-an-app-like-lego/embed-a-xib-in-a-storyboard-953edf274155

And you can get the open source BFWControls framework here:
https://github.com/BareFeetWare/BFWControls

And here's a simple extract of the code that drives it, in case you're curious:
https://gist.github.com/barefeettom/f48f6569100415e0ef1fd530ca39f5b4

Tom

Answer (score -3):

The "correct" answer is that you are not meant to make re-usable views with corresponding nibs. If a view subclass is valuable as a reusable object it rarely will need a nib to go with it. Take for example every view subclass provided by UIKit. Part of this thinking is a view subclass that is actually valuable wont be implemented using a nib, which is the general view at Apple.

Usually when you use a view in nib or storyboard you will want to tweak it graphically for the given use case anyway.

You might consider using "copy paste" for recreating same or similar views instead of making separate nibs. I this believe accomplishes the same requirements and it will keep you more or less in line with what Apple is doing.

Comment: I'm not following your argument. You seem to be saying "if it's reusable, just code it all up as a class (layout and all)", which if that were the case, why aren't all view controllers done that way, as well as any useful view hierarchy?

Comment: This is an interesting perspective — that re-usable views should always be implemented in code, and that xibs and storyboards are only there for assembling non re-usable views from the re-usable views. It is quite consistent with what the tools enable. But do you have any other reason to say this is "the general view at Apple"?

Comment: I think the point is to figure out a way to do it, in spite of the general view at Apple.  This approach seems counterproductive; reusing UIView xibs that have modular configuration is pretty commonplace and has plenty of applications.  The "why would you ever want to do this?" approach is unhelpful for anyone building a serious application that is necessarily going to have to go against "what Apple is doing" in some cases.  (unless you're developing code for Apple themselves, that is)

Comment: Travis: I'm saying if a view you've designed in Interface Builder is useful there is a much easier way to duplicate it. You select it, press command-C, then press command-V. Very few steps compared to locating it in a nib.

If you have a view that is *exactly* the same everywhere, is used in lots of places, and that you want to be able to tweak easily than there is a new way to do that. But in the many many apps I've worked on this just doesn't come up.

DivideByZer0: It's helpful in that the author is trying to force their workflow onto the tools instead of embracing the tools.