# How to properly subclass a view class which is loaded from xib in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, subclass, xib

I'm trying to understand how to properly subclass view which is loaded from a xib in Swift.

I've got `TitleDetailLabel` class which is subclass of `UIControl`. This class has `titleLabel` and `detailLabel` outlets which are `UILabel`s.

```
class TitleDetailLabel: UIControl {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeAfterUsingCoder(aDecoder: NSCoder) -> AnyObject? {
        return NTHAwakeAfterUsingCoder(aDecoder, nibName: "TitleDetailLabel")
    }

    func setTitle(text: String) {
        self.titleLabel.text = text
    }

    func setDetailText(text: String) {
        self.detailLabel.text = text
    }
}
```

XIB structure:

- Placeholders

  - File's Owner: `NSObject` (not changed)
  - First Responder
- Title Detail Label - `UIView` - `TitleDetailLabel` class

  - Label - `UILabel` - title label
  - Label - `UILabel` - detail label

In Storyboard I've got view controller and placeholder - simple `UIView` object with constraints.

I've created extension to `UIView` class to simplify swapping placeholder with object I am interested in. It works good with this `TitleDetailLabel` class. Here is how it looks:

```
extension UIView {
    public func NTHAwakeAfterUsingCoder(aDecoder: NSCoder, nibName: String) -> AnyObject? {
        if (self.subviews.count == 0) {
            let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
            let loadedView = nib.instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil).first as UIView

            /// set view as placeholder is set
            loadedView.frame = self.frame
            loadedView.autoresizingMask = self.autoresizingMask
            loadedView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints())

            for constraint in self.constraints() as [NSLayoutConstraint] {
                var firstItem = constraint.firstItem as UIView
                if firstItem == self {
                    firstItem = loadedView
                }

                var secondItem = constraint.secondItem as UIView?
                if secondItem != nil {
                    if secondItem! == self {
                        secondItem = loadedView
                    }
                }

                loadedView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstItem, attribute: constraint.firstAttribute, relatedBy: constraint.relation, toItem: secondItem, attribute: constraint.secondAttribute, multiplier: constraint.multiplier, constant: constraint.constant))
            }

            return loadedView
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

I decided to create `BasicTitleDetailLabel` subclass of `TitleDetailLabel` class to keep there some configuration code and other stuff.

```
class BasicTitleDetailLabel: TitleDetailLabel {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }

    override init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.NTHCadetGrayColor()
        self.detailLabel.textColor = UIColor.NTHLinkWaterColor()
    }
}
```

But application crashes every time after I changed class of this placeholder from `TitleDetailLabel` to `BasicTitleDetailLabel`.

App crashes because `titleLabel` and `detailLabel` are nil.

How can I properly use this `TitleDetailLabel` class with xib and how to subclass this correctly? I don't want to create another xib which looks the same like the first one to use subclass.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the error returned on crash?

Comment: App crashes because after `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` I called `self.setup()` and in this moment outlets are `nil` (`Unexpectedly found nil...`).  `awakeAfterUsingCoder:` return object of type `TitleDetailLabel`. I read something that this is not possible to create object of different class using xibs.

Comment: Why are you assuming that the outlets are around after init? They will not be around until after the xib has been loaded. Does it work if you just check that the labels aren't nil before trying to access them? To make this more clear, you can set the outlets as optionals and use `if let` before accessing them.

Comment: Hi @TomaszSzulc, Did you find any solution for this. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you make the set the File's Owner for the .xib file to the .swift file. Also add an outlet for the root view and then load the xib from code. This is how I did it for a similar project:

```
import UIKit
class ResuableCustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBAction func buttonTap(sender: UIButton) {
        label.text = "Hi"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ReusableCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

It is a little different than yours but you can add the `init:frame` method. If you have an `awakeFromNib` method then don't load the `setup` method in both `awakeFromNib` and `init:coder`.

My full answer for the above code project is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34524346/3681880) or watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3MawJVxTgk).

Comment: Best answer I've seen for this