# Loading a custom view in a storyboard from a separated nib file

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, interface-builder, xib

I've customized an `UIView` in its own `.xib` file in order to being able to reuse it in several scenes of my `storyboard`. It is only a view with no view controller behind. I'm trying to load it in the `storyboard` and to see it in `Interface Builder` in the scenes I want to place it, with no success. I've been looking for a way to do that and I didn't found a post with an answer that worked for me.

I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 and my app is targeting iOS 7 and above. Could somebody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [I was also trying to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34524346/3681880) and making the view @IBDesignable wasn't working for me. Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is make a subclass of UIView with its xib (CustomView.h, CustomView.m and CustomView.xib). And add a UIView to your controller on storyboard. Then assign its class to your custom view class.

This works without loading custom xib via code. But you cannot see the subviews of your custom view on storyboard.

Comment: That's what in fact I was trying to do, to see the subviews on the storyboard... thanks