# IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent raised a "NSInternalInconsistencyException" exception: Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibdesignable

**I use stroyboard create preview from xib, But I got these error:**

```
file:///Users/miaios/Desktop/Demo/XibDemo/XibDemo/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent raised a "NSInternalInconsistencyException" exception: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/miaios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XibDemo-hkqfrktawlqpokczkfobsrmkfxqy/Build/Intermediates/IBDesignables/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XibDemo.app> (loaded)' with name 'HXXibView'

file:///Users/miaios/Desktop/Demo/XibDemo/XibDemo/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of HXXibView: The agent threw an exception.
```

**Code:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface HXXibView : UIView

@property (nonnull, nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable NSString *text;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end

@implementation HXXibView

#pragma mark - Init Methods
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self xibSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self xibSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    _label.text = text;
}
- (NSString *)text {
    return _label.text;
}


#pragma mark - Private Methods
- (void)xibSetup {
    UIView *view = [self loadViewFromNib];
    view.frame = self.bounds;
    [self addSubview:view];
}

- (UIView *)loadViewFromNib {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[HXXibView class]];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([HXXibView class]) bundle:bundle];
    UIView *view = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    return view;
}

@end
```

**Xib load by `File's Owner` Class, not `UIView` Class, On `iOS8` is normal, `iOS7` is error**

**Error path:**

> 1.Change project target to `iOS7`.
>
> 2.Quit Xcode.
>
> 3.Clean DerivedData folder.
>
> 4.Open project.
>
> 5.Selected `Main.storyboard`, and see preview.

**This is [Demo](https://github.com/shicang1990/XibDemo)**

Comment: Try making it not @IBDesignable for now. That's what I had to do to get this error to go away for [this project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34524346/3681880).