# IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent raised a "CALayerInvalidGeometry" exception

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ibdesignable

After I add `@IBDesignable` to a view controller,

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class IvCalcViewController: UIViewController {
  // ...
}
```

the following error shows up in Xcode 7.2 (7C68):

> file:///.../Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed
>   to update auto layout status: The agent raised a
>   "CALayerInvalidGeometry" exception: CALayer position contains NaN:
>   [207 nan]

I can still run the app in Simulator when the error is there.

[image]

When I click on the error, Xcode jumps to the ViewController in StoryBoard but does not highlight what's wrong.

How can I clear the error?

p.s. I have removed all auto-layout constrains from the StoryBoard already...

Update: one way to clear the error:

- remove all `@IBDesignable` from the source
- close the project
- re-open the project

So the question becomes: are there some minimum auto-layout requirements to meet when using `@IBDesignable`?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am coming across something similar when I try to make [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34524346/3681880) @IBDesignable, although I think my problem may be related to loading the layout from an xib file.