# Infinite loop on instantiated view from xib on storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I'm trying to instantiate a xib from storyboard but I'm getting an infinite loop. I have seen this snippet working on a video but I'm probably doing something wrong. I can understand why, but not how to make it work... Txs for help ! )

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup()
{
    print("INFINITE LOOP :(")

    self.view = self.loadViewFromNib()
    self.view.frame = bounds
    self.addSubview(self.view)

}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView
{
    let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "ItemView", bundle: .main)
    let view: UIView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}
```

Comment: What class is this code in? What class is `view` declared as? What class is `ItemView` setup to be in the nib?

Comment: It seems loadViewFromNib will call init again.

Comment: It s my class ItemView: UIView

Comment: It looks like your view is trying to load _itself_ from the nib. Hence the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Interface Builder, where defined your view, you should set the *File Owner's* custom class to `ItemView` (or to other classes you are creating). Do not set the view class.

Unfortunately, StackOverflow won't let me post images, but see the screenshots below.

[View with no class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ntaP.png)

[File owner's class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP9Zq.png)

Comment: Yes exact ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is misleading. The class of the File’s Owner is irrelevant in this situation.

Comment: The File's Owner references the outlets and receives actions. Usually, it's not the same class/instance as the view, (i.e. a view controller and its corresponding view). But it's not [uncommon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set?rq=1) for custom views to be structured that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown enough code, but it looks like you're effectively doing this (I've simplified your code to focus on the problem):

```
class ItemView : UIView {
    // called when an ItemView is loaded from a nib
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }
    // called to load an ItemView from a nib
    func loadViewFromNib(){
        let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "ItemView", bundle: .main)
        let view: UIView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
}
```

So it seems this view is an ItemView loaded from a nib, and as it is loaded it tries to load another ItemView from a nib, which tries to load another ItemView from a nib....

A view cannot load *itself* from a nib like that. You need to put all that code in the class of some *other* view that will act as the ItemView's superview.

Comment: Yep nib.instantiate() calls init that calls loadViewFromNib() etc...
I have no problem when creating the view by code.

Comment: So what is the right way to implement init when using the storyboard ?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. I can only explain why this way is circular.

Comment: I just want to instantiate this exact custom view from the story board (dragging a uiview on the storyboard and making its class an 'ItemView')...
 I'm new at swift pardon me just being an Android developer :)

Comment: But this exact custom view is already configured in a _nib_ (a _.xib_ file). It makes no sense to stick it in the storyboard and then say you want it to come from the nib. Pick one.

Comment: Yes it does. You can create your custom view using a xib and use it from the storyboard. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: No. You didn't read what I said. My answer tells you that your mistake is that the view in the storyboard is the _same_ class as the view in the nib. And that's why you get an infinite loop. My answer says that you need the view in the storyboard to be a _different_ class from the view in the nib.

Answer (score 0):

Found! This can be helpfull for some people

I was setting the view class instead of the "owner" of the xib file! So the xib was creating the view that was loading the xib and so on...

Thanks to @RealNmae on the link:
[How do I create a custom iOS view class and instantiate multiple copies of it (in IB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251202/how-do-i-create-a-custom-ios-view-class-and-instantiate-multiple-copies-of-it-i/34524346#34524346)

Comment: That is exactly what my answer said. The class of the view you load must not be the class of this view, or we get a loop. The stuff about the File’s Owner is irrelevant.